# Applying Fubini to $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |f(t)|^2 e^{-st} \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}\;\mathrm dt \, \mathrm ds, $

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Consider the double integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |f(t)|^2 e^{-st} \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}\;\mathrm dt \, \mathrm ds, $$
where $f \in L^2(0,\infty)$. 
This double integral appears when computing the norm of the Laplace transform as a map of $L^2(0,\infty) \to L^2(0,\infty)$.

To continue with the computation, I must interchange the order of integration, i.e. I would like to apply Fubini's theorem. However, I'm not seeing why Fubini's theorem can be applied here.

I was thinking of splitting the domain of integration, and then considering each sub-integral separately, but I would guess that there is a better way of seeing it.
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you know Tonelli's theorem?

Comment: @zhw. I didn't, until now. Thanks for the comment!